# Develop .NET 5 on Codespaces

Tags: .net, codespaces

Is it possible to use dotnet 5 on Visual Studio Codespaces? I have followed the instructions for ubuntu 18.04 found here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-ubuntu#1804-

After running:

```
sudo apt-get install -y dotnet-sdk-5.0
```

I get the response:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
dotnet-sdk-5.0 is already the newest version (5.0.100-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 39 not upgraded.
```

When I run the `dotnet --list-sdks` I get the following versions:

```
1.1.14 [/home/codespace/.dotnet/sdk]
2.1.807 [/home/codespace/.dotnet/sdk]
2.2.402 [/home/codespace/.dotnet/sdk]
3.0.103 [/home/codespace/.dotnet/sdk]
3.1.301 [/home/codespace/.dotnet/sdk]
```

Why is 5.0 not showing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current work around is to run:

```
curl -sSL 'https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/820db713-c9a5-466e-b72a-16f2f5ed00e2/628aa2a75f6aa270e77f4a83b3742fb8/dotnet-sdk-5.0.100-linux-x64.tar.gz' | tar -xzC ~/.dotnet
```